# What is the best way to handle this constraint in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers, constraints

I have SMS based survey application which takes in a survey domain, and a answer.

I've gotten requests for detailed DDL, so....  The database looks like [this](https://imgur.com/7QFE.jpg)

SurveyAnswer.Answer must be unique within all **active** Surveys for that SurveyDomain.  In SQL terms, this should always return 0..1 rows:

```
select * from survey s, surveyanswer sa
where s.surveyid = sa.surveyid and
      s.active = 1 and
      s.surveydomainid = @surveydomainid
      sa.answer = @answer
```

I plan on handling this constraint at the application level, but would also like some database integrity to be enforced.  What is the best way to do this?  Trigger?  Possible in a constraint?

Comment: Can you provider the DDL? What are your primary keys?

Comment: I added the DDL in the easiest way I could...  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are covering 2 tables there is AFAIK only 2 ways to enforce this.

1. Trigger as you suggested.
2. Indexed view with unique constraint accross the 3 columns.

As far as reliability is concerned I would go for the Indexed view but the only downside is that it will be difficult to understand by third parties.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add a constraint that is implemented in a UDF like this:

```
alter table MyTable add constraint complexConstraint
check (dbo.complexConstraintFct()=0)
```

Where complexConstraintFct would be a function containing a query on other tables. However this approach has some issues as check constraints were designed to be evaluated on a single row at a time but updates can affect more that one row at a time.

So, the bottom line is: **stick with triggers**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using stored procedures to perform DML operations, you could add a guard clause to the SP that adds answers to surveys to check for the existence of an equivalent answer.  You could then either throw an exception or return a status code to indicate that the answer could not be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it at the row level (eg CHECK constraint) so you have to have something that can view all rows

A trigger can send "nice" messages, but they run after the DML statement. You have fine control over processing.

An indexed view prevents the DML statement, but it gives a technical error message. It's an extra object *and indexes* to maintain.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're saying is that for any active question, the tuple (surveyDomain, surveyQuestion, surveyAnswer) must be unique?

Or in other words, survey:surveyanswer is 1:1 if the survey is active, even though survey:surveyanswer is set up to be 1:many.

If so, the answer is to change your table structure. Adding a nullable activeAnswerId column to survey will effectively make the relation 1:1; your existing constraint unique SurveyId (or unique SurveyId, SurvetDomainId) will suffice to enforce uniqueness.

Indeed, unless I'm misunderstanding, I'm surprised that Survey has a Question column; I'd expect Survey:Question to be 1:many (a survey has many questions) or even many:many, if a question can show up on more than one survey.

More generally, I suspect the reason that figuring out how to enforce the constraint is difficult and requires "heroics" like triggers or user defined functions, is a symptom of a schema that doesn't accurately model your problem domain.

OP comments:

> no, you're missing it. Survey:Answer is 1:n. "Question" is the survey question – Tuple would be (SurveyDomain.SurveyDomainId, Survey.Answer)

You mean that for every domain, there's at most one answer? Again, looking at your schema, it's misleading at best. A SurveyDomain has many Surveys (each of which has a Question column) and a Survey has many Answers? ([Schema](https://imgur.com/7QFE.jpg))

But if the Survey's active bit is set, there should be only one Answer?

Is Survey a misnomer for Question?

It's really not clear what you're trying to model.

Again, if it's hard to add a constraint, that suggests that your model doesn't work.

Comment: no, you're missing it.  Survey:Answer is 1:n.  "Question" is the survey question

Comment: Tuple would be (SurveyDomain.SurveyDomainId, Survey.Answer)

Comment: Ignore the "Question" column if that helps.  The Question column is merely the "question" text for the survey!  A Survey has N answers!

Comment: A Survey contains one and only one question.  The survey IS a question and the question is a survey.  Again, pretend the "question" column didn't freakin exist.